# Keep Getting Compilation Errors on ASP.net Website

Tags: asp.net

I have a client website where I recently started getting compilation errors:

> CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'AspNet.StarterKits.Classifieds.Web.CategorySelectionChangedEventHandler
>   [c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\party\db314a04\fbc40acd\App_Code.nhjh6o2h.dll]' to
>   'AspNet.StarterKits.Classifieds.Web.CategorySelectionChangedEventHandler
>   []'

On this line:

```
<uc1:CategoryPath ID="CategoryPath" Runat="server" OnCategorySelectionChanged="CategoryPath_CategorySelectionChanged" />
```

I have not made any changes to this particular website in over a year.

I discovered that if I rename the web.config file in the root directory of this site, then rename it back, the site seems to recompile and these compilation errors go away for a while. They eventually come back in a period of a few hours.

I suspect the website is crashing somehow and renaming the web.config file is causing a recompile or something similar. This solution always works to fix it but it isn't feasible for me or the client to be doing this multiple times a day.

Any ideas where to start in even looking into this error? This website is on a remote web host and I don't have direct access to login to the web server to check ISS or event viewer for any sort of errors unfortunately.

Comment: maybe the server was updated? dll version probably changed.

Comment: This site is a shopping cart site. I have two shopping cart sites on the same server, simply in different directories. Only one is having this issue. If it was something affecting the entire server, I would expect both shopping carts to have this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by spending a few hours on the phone with the web host and convincing them the problem was on their end. They didn't share the details of what they did to resolve this issue, but it went away after getting on them to do something about it. It wouldn't surprise me if Aristos's suggestion of stopping IIS and deleting temp files worked but the control panel of this remote website didn't allow me to do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Do this steps :

1. Make a file called `app_offline.htm` on your root of your web site, and the site will go off line.
2. Open and change your `web.config` just add an enter on the end, and save it.
3. Rename or delete the `app_offline.html` file

to trigger a better recompile and check again what needs update. If this fails then the second think that you can do is:

1. Stop the IIS, and go to the temporary directory `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\` and clear it to force the recompile of everything, just in case that can not find what is change.

Comment: So far, so good on the app_offline.htm fix. I'll feel good about this once it lasts more than a day. The site hasn't stayed up for a full day yet since this started.

Comment: Unfortunately the app_offile.html fix didn't resolve the problem long term. 

Because of where the application is hosted, I don't have access to delete the temporary files or to restart IIS. 

Any other ideas???

Comment: @Kris Yes, open the trace, to see on your log the line that this throw happens maybe this can help you to find the real issue. `<compiler  compilerOptions="/D:DTRACE" ...>`